# I can't post on Facebook Page Wall Timeline

Tags: facebook, api

I have a problem with PHP API 5 - I try to post to my Facebook Page Wall Timeline, but instead post goes to: "VISITORS POSTS" section (????).

I tried a lot of different scripts, but the result is always the same.

Maybe there is some problem with app or page setup?

There is my code:

```
<?


require_once 'FacebookSDK/src/facebook/autoload.php';


$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APPID',
  'app_secret' => 'SECR',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$data = [
  'message' => 'My example.',

];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/PAGEID/feed', $data, 'ACCESSTOKEN');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];




?>
```

My accesstoken shows:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "access_token": 

"XX",
         "category": "Company",
         "name": "XX.XX",
         "id": "XX",
         "perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "before": "XX",
         "after": "XX"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: SOLUTION: Use page accesskey instead of default accesskey

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a Page Access Token if you want to post as the Page itself.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish

> **Permissions**
>
> - A user access token with publish_actions permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that person. Posts will appear in the voice of the user.
> - A page access token with publish_pages permission can be used to publish new posts on behalf of that page. Posts will appear in the voice of the page.